# How to make a generic add Class?

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Generic methods and numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850970/java-generic-methods-and-numbers)

How to make the below class generic so that i can pass Integer,Float ,Double etc?

```
class Add {
public Integer sum (Integer a, Integer b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

**Edit:**
I have tried

```
class Add <T> {
    public T sum (T a, T b) {
        return a+b;
    }
```

am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: You already know the exact thing to Google. Come on.

Comment: Please read basics of Generics at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360035/how-to-handle-numbers-in-a-generic-fashion

Answer (score -2):

```
class Add {
public Number sum (Number a, Number b) {
    //logic
}
```

Comment: This would achieve desired functionality, however this isn't really what the OP was asking for.

Comment: @DougRamsey If it achieves desired functionality; I do not feel it should be down-voted ! And we are not sure what is more important for OP --> Whether it is functionality or way to achieve the same ! Neverthless, it can be a neutral answer but not deserve to be down voted

Comment: I agree, that is why I did not down vote :)

Comment: -1 You've left out the trickiest part, which is the implementation. Consider that a `Number` can be anything from a `Byte` to `BigDecimal`. Also, keeping the return type `Integer` is inflexible.

Comment: I do agree that return type should have been Number. My mistake. Regarding implementation I would recommend to put a logic for each type of Number possible.